# Use pySerial to list open serial ports *from python script*, not from the command line

Tags: python, pyserial

So I've got a serial device, however the serial port changes most times I reconnect it.
What I want to do is to list all serial ports, iterate over them until I find the correct one, and then connect to that one.
I know that I can list all ports from the commandline like:

```bash
$ python -m serial.tools.list_ports
/dev/cu.YYYY
/dev/cu.XXXX
ZZZZ ports found
```

I want to do that from a python, but this doesn't work:

```py
>>> import serial
>>> for port in serial.tools.list_ports:
...     print(f'Current port: {port}')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'tools'
```

What can I do? I really don't want to execute `python -m serial.tools.list_ports` as an external shell command, as it just seems silly since the library already has an API for python scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I can explain it, but sometimes Python is fussy about dotted imports. Also to get an iterable within a script, you can use `comports()`

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial.tools.list_ports
>>> for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
...     print(f'Current port: {port}')
...
Current port: COM1 - Communications Port (COM1)
>>>
```

The serial.tools.list_ports module is [documented here](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html?highlight=list_ports#module-serial.tools.list_ports).

Comment: Thanks! that answers my question, but raises two others: 1) Do you know where I can read up more about the funky dotted imports? and 2) so is comports() documented anywhere in pySerial?

Comment: I don't have a good reference for dotted imports. That's probably not even the right name. But comports() is the very first function documented on the serial.tools.list_ports page linked to in my answer.